# Window, on scroll script won't trigger / fire?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this script:

```
<script type="text / javascript">
/* Popup on scroll. */
jQuery(function($){
$(window).one('scroll',function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
    $('.popup').css({display: 'flex'}).fadeIn();
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    $('.popup').css({display: 'none'}).fadeOut();
  }
});
});

jQuery(function($){
$('.popup-link').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest(".popup").remove();
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = "block";
});
});
</script>
```

Usage in HTML:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-page">
        <a class="popup-link" href="url" target="_blank">
This is LINK TEXT.
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason it works if page is reloaded on half, but no, it does not fire at all, and before it was working so I have no idea what happened.
I use this on wordpress website.

Comment: Is this using `one` instead of `on` on purpose?

Comment: Please tag appropriately. There is no `php` or `wordpess` involved in what you have shown us so far (tags removed.)

Comment: `$(window).one` registers single event which cancels it self on first occurrence. You would probably need `$(window).on`.

Comment: It was on purpose, but I have two functions, this one is .one, another one is .on.
Function with .on works but second part does not return .content css to display="block", actualy it removes .content, and function with .one does not fire at all.

I can use only .on on both functions as well, but how do I solve second part?

Comment: Or in another case, I need to use .one, so it does not fire on .content again and make its css display="none"

Comment: Can’t make much sense of what you are trying to explain here. Your scroll handler, that you added with `.one`, doesn’t have anything to do with `.content` in the first place. You manipulate that in the click handler for `.popup-link`, so how are the two even related?

Comment: Once click handler fires, it removes popup, revealing .content, and that is fine.
But if you do single scroll, using .on, first function will fire again, which is now not possible to show popup as it is removed, but it is possible to make .content block display set to none again.

Comment: Simply, use the `.off()` when you need to remove an already set instener  by the `.on()` method. See the example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.one()`.
To afterwards remove any listeners use the [`.off()` method](https://api.jquery.com/off/):

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // POPUP
  // Yep, all you need for all your popups
  $("[data-popup]").on("click", function() {
    $(this.dataset.popup).toggleClass("show");
  });

  // CUSTOM POPUP STUFF
  const $popupCustom = $("#popup-custom");

  function popupScroll() {
    $popupCustom.toggleClass("show", $(window).scrollTop() > 100);
  }
  
  function popupDestroy() {
    // Remove listener from window scroll using .off()
    $(window).off('scroll', popupScroll);
  }

  // Listen for window scroll:
  $(window).on('scroll', popupScroll);
  
  // Destroy the scroll listener on click:
  $("#popup-destroy").on("click", popupDestroy);

});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh; /* DEMO ONLY */
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  transition: 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popup.show {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup-page {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-custom" class="popup">
  <div class="popup-page">
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    <button type="button" data-popup="#popup-custom" id="popup-destroy">DON'T SHOW ON SCROLL AGAIN!</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h1>THIS IS SOME CONTENT</h1>
  Scroll or<br>
  <button type="button" data-popup="#popup-custom">SHOW POPUP</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No.
Read comments under question.
.on makes problem on document.getElementById('content').style.display = "block";

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN the scroll event fires once for every pixel scrolled. Unless you only want to detect 1px of movement (which is incredibly unlikely to be the case), then the OPs use of `one()` is incorrect and this answer is valid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I actually think he wants to permanently remove the scroll listener. Edited my answer.

Comment: On scroll, class="popup hide show" and its still display="none", fixed by adding block to show class

Comment: @rudiger sorry forgot to remove the class `"hide"` from the popup. Anyways. There's the demo above. Hit *Run* and have fun.

Comment: Thanks.
Can you tell me whats the best way to implement
document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none" on function popupScroll() {
    $popupCustom.toggleClass("show", $(window).scrollTop() > 100);
  }

Comment: @rudiger JS should not be the one to dictate CSS rules and mess things with the design. Use JS to simply toggle a class like in the example above. Than specify in CSS what that class does. Study the above code to understand it. it toggles a `.show`. See in CSS what it does. - To do the inverse, use a `.hide`. You got the idea.